# NOTEPAD++ , How to insert some word to special characters

Tags: characters

> how to
>
> A/B/1 A/B/5 A/B/8 A/B/9
>
> become
>
> C/D/1?XYZ C/D/5?XYZ C/D/8?XYZ C/D/9?XYZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace 'A/B/(\d+)' with 'C/D/\1?XYZ'

\1 refers to the first match in the regular expression. The first match is (\d+) in the replace string. (\d+) means find one or more digits, that is a character 0-9.

Comment: dear friend, not always "\1" but 1 5 8 9 keep in letter,, please help .  example for another A/B/46855 become C/D/46855?XYZ

Comment: \1 refers to the first match in the regular expression.  The first match is `(\d)` in the replace string.  `(\d)` means find one digit, that is a character 0-9.

Comment: for this example A/B/46855 become C/D/46855?XYZ not solved,, please help to solve this example,,

Comment: editted answer to handle multiple digit answers